# Remove old Postgres version from Mac

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to remove an old version of Postgres on my local Macbook Pro but cannot figure it out. In PG Admin I see two servers, version 9.2 and 9.4. When I try to run Heroku commands such as pg:pull, its referring to the old server. But my database is located on the new one, version 9.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uninstaller is located in /library/PostgreSQL/9.2/uninstall-postgresql. Running that uninstaller removed my old version and left the newer one in place.

Comment: The uninstaller app does not remove everything. The data folder is left. And several config files scattered around the OS folders remain.